# Creating polygon based on spatial extent in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon

Is there anyway that I can input:

1. The Coordinates System (projected is OK)
2. The bounding box

and create a rectangle polygon based on these?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I assume you have points/a polygon associated with your coordinate system.  Try using Arc's [Minimum Bounding Geometry (Data Management)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000003q000000).  Then select the "Envelope" or "Rectangle by Area/Width" geometry type.

[image]